# string symbol appears white after ','

Tags: javascript

Here's my code:

```
const sillySentence = (adjective, verb, noun) => {
  console.log(`I am so ${adjective} because I ${verb} coding! Time to write some more awesome ${noun}!`);
};

sillySentence('adjective' , 'verb', 'noen');
```

It seems to run fine. Although (can't see it here) after the 'adjective', the first ' in front of verb appears white instead of yellow and comments out the rest of the parameter. is this normal or do I have any flaws in my code?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: What browser are you using? I am on Chrome 83 and it looks fine

Comment: I think it might be something in the IDE?

Comment: Please may you add more context around where you are seeing this issue?